# Passport.js: how to access user object after authentication?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Passport.js to login a user with username and password.  I'm essentially using the sample code from the Passport site.  Here are the relevant parts (I think) of my code:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
        }
        if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
        }
        return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));

app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login/fail', failureFlash: false }),
    function(req, res) {
        // Successful login
        //console.log("Login successful.");
        // I CAN ACCESS req.user here
});
```

This seems to login correctly.  However, I would like to be able to access the login user's information in other parts of the code, such as:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    // How can I get the user's login info here?
    console.log(req.user);  // <------ this outputs undefined
});
```

I have checked other questions on SO, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Thank you!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You'll need to make sure that you register a [middleware](http://expressjs.com/api.html#middleware) that populates `req.session` before registering the passport middlewares.

For example the following uses [express cookieSession middleware](http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieSession)

```
app.configure(function() {

  // some code ...

  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieSession()); // Express cookie session middleware 
  app.use(passport.initialize());   // passport initialize middleware
  app.use(passport.session());      // passport session middleware 

  // more code ...

});
```

Comment: This support setup code does not indicate how the user is finally acquired out of the session.

Answer (score 74):

Late to the party but found this unanswered after googling the answer myself.

Inside the request will be a `req.user` object that you can work withr.

Routes like so:

```
app.get('/api/portfolio', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), stocks.buy);
```

Controller like this:

```
buy: function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.body);
      //res.json({lel: req.user._id});
      res.json({lel: req.user});
    }
```

Comment: This should be the right answer as it addresses more directly the issue... In case of a stateless REST API, this is the cay to go...

Comment: What if after logging in req.user appears as undefined?

Comment: hmm I have that, but still have an issue, any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

In reference to the [Passport documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/), the user object is contained in req.user. See below.

```
    app.post('/login',
      passport.authenticate('local'),function(req, res) {
       // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
       // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
       res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
     });
```

That way, you can access your user object from the page you redirect to.

In case you get stuck, you can refer to [my Github project](https://github.com/iLabs-Makerere/OpenLabs-Node.js/blob/master/routes/index.js) where I implemented it clearly.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I never figured out where to actually access req.user, and this sums it up perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: passport documentation link is expired, edit your answer

Comment: Updated! Thanks @Thecave3

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty new to javascript but as I understand it from the tutorials you have to implement some session `middleware` first as indicated by 250R.

```js
const session = require('express-session')
const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

let sess = {
    genid: (req) => {
        console.log('Inside the session middleware')
        console.log(req.sessionID)
        return uuid()
    },
    store: new FileStore(),
    secret: 'keyboard cat', // password from environment
    resave: false,
    rolling: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        HttpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 30 * 60 * 1000 // 30 minutes
    }
}

app.use(session(sess))

// call passport after configuring the session with express-session
// as it rides on top of it
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

// then you will be able to use the 'user' property on the `req` object
// containing all your session details
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.user)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

> [`res.render`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.render) accepts an optional parameter that is an object containing local variables for the view.

If you use [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/) and already authenticated the user then [`req.user`](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/) contains the authenticated user.

```
// app.js
app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  res.render('./dashboard', { user: req.user })
})
```

---

```
// index.ejs
<%= user.name %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your route this way as follows.

```
router.post('/login',
passport.authenticate('local' , {failureRedirect:'/login', failureFlash: true}),
function(req, res) {
   res.redirect('/home?' + req.user.username);
});
```

In the above code snippet, you can access and pass any field of the user object as "req.user.field_name" to the page you want to redirect. One thing to note here is that the base url of the page you want to redirect to should be followed by a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

late to party but this worked for me

use this in your app.js

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  next();
})
```

get current user details in client side like ejs

```
<%= locals.currentUser.[parameter like name || email] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for those using Next.js:**

Oddly, [**—> the solution <—**](https://github.com/hoangvvo/next-connect/tree/21c9c73fe3746e66033fd51e2aa01d479e267ad6#runreq-res) comes from a [recently removed part of the README](https://github.com/hoangvvo/next-connect/commit/707ce0a8e1378d7c1204dae72ef519f77eabda49#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5) of `next-connect`, but works just as it should. You can ignore the typescript parts if you're using plain JS.

The key part is the `getServerSideProps` function in `./src/pages/index` (or whichever file you want to get the user object for).

```js
// —> ./src/authMiddleware.ts
// You'll need your session, initialised passport and passport with the session,
// so here's an example of how we've got ours setup, yours may be different

//
// Create the Passport middleware for SAML auth.
//
export const ppinit = passport.initialize();

//
// Set up Passport to work with expressjs sessions.
//
export const ppsession = passport.session();

//
// Set up expressjs session handling middleware
//
export const sess = session({
  secret: process.env.sessionSecret as string,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: sessionStore,
});
```

```js
// —> ./src/pages/index.ts

// update your user interface to match yours
export interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface ExtendedReq extends NextApiRequest {
  user: User;
}

interface ServerProps {
  req: ExtendedReq;
  res: NextApiResponse;
}

interface ServerPropsReturn {
  user?: User;
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }: ServerProps) {
  const middleware = nc()
    .use(sess, ppinit, ppsession)
    .get((req: Express.Request, res: NextApiResponse, next) => {
      next();
    });

  try {
    await middleware.run(req, res);
  } catch (e) {
    // handle the error
  }

  const props: ServerPropsReturn = {};
  if (req.user) props.user = req.user;
  return { props };
}

interface Props {
  user?: User;
}

//
// A trivial Home page - it should show minimal info if the user is not authenticated.
//
export default function Home({ user }: Props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>My app</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <h1>Welcome to My App {user?.name}</h1>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```