# How can I determine my logged in status on the client? [finished]

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

I'm using Express/Passport.  All my files are served statically like this.

```
// static bundle from webpack
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/../client-react/dist'));
```

So when I'm on the client I have not way to know if I'm logged in.

Passport is working fine and I am able to get profile data on the server.

Ajax Request is here:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "/api/items",
      success: (results) => {
        console.log(results);
        this.props.dispatch({type: 'updateBookmarks', bookmarks: results});
      }
    });
  }
```

Server Response is here:

```
router.route('/items').get((req, res) => {

    console.log(req.user);

    DB.selectAllDomains().then((results) => {
        res.json(results);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The client doesn't know if user is logged in. Client makes a request to your server, you should have access to req.user on your sever if passport is integrated properly. The server can respond with key/value in req.user . Now your client has received info about the logged in user.

Check this out [Passport.js: how to access user object after authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951789/passport-js-how-to-access-user-object-after-authentication)

Comment: Your sever needs to respond with req.user 
example: res.json(req.user);

Use fetch or ajax to make a request to your sever.

Comment: Can you post you ajax request here?

Comment: Do you have body parser installed?

Comment: Disregard the previous comment. Uninstall the body parser. You don't need it. Can you post your ajax request. Sorry, its hard to help without seeing your ajax request.

Comment: Im curious: use 

  $.ajax({
      url: "/api/items",
      success: function(results) {
        console.log(results);
        this.props.dispatch({type: 'updateBookmarks', bookmarks: results});
      }
    });
  }

Comment: You ned add 
`type: "GET"` to your request. I missed that. Also don't assume. I haven't seen a arrow function example in there docs as well.

Comment: Add 
`type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', ` to your ajax request. Im trying to help.
Here is a example: https://jsfiddle.net/hofo/x7s9c4wL/