# In passport not getting req.user value in node js

Tags: javascript, nodejs-server

I have an app in node js with javascript and I am trying to get the req.user but it's coming.
Below is the code example which I am using

```
const app=express();
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
var session=require('express-session');
var passport= require('passport');
var saml= require('passport-saml');
app.use(bodyparser.json);
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false});
app.use(session ({secret:'secretval',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,}));
app.use(passport.initialize({}));
app.use(passport.session({}));
```

And I have below methods,

```
app.get('/login',passport.authenticate('samlstrategy',{session:true}),(req,res)=>{
res.redirect('myurl');
console.log('logged in user is as'+req.user);
return;
}

app.get('/login/callback',passport.authenticate('samlstrategy',{session:true}),(req,res)=>{
res.redirect('myurl');
return;
}
```

When I am invoking the url for /login it's working and user is getting authenticated by passport api.but I am not getting the user details in request.
How can I get the user in req object.

Comment: Any update on this

Answer (score 0):

If `user` is a get parameter then you forgot `query` after `req`

Use

```
req.query.user
```

Comment: passport is req is returning user after successful Authorization of the given user for azure.i am not passing any parameter with get('/login1') and not able to print anything within this login api

Comment: Does anything from here help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951789/passport-js-how-to-access-user-object-after-authentication)

Comment: Tried but of no use.not able to get the user in login api

Comment: Does `res.redirect()` end the request?

Comment: Didn't get you working first time on node. As I think it's ending

Comment: Will any code run after `res.redirect()`?

Comment: No. after redirect no code

Comment: Try seeing if you can log the user before redirect.

Comment: I am able to log that in login/callback but not getting that value in login